# NSMutableArray from another view returns empty

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have two UIViews. One UIView, called `SelectText` has an ivar of `NSMutableArray` which is populated after performing a certain function.

Here is a snippet code:

```
- (void)fillDrawPoints
  {
      //the codes....
     [self.drawnPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:currPoint]];
  }
```

**NOTE:** The `drawnPoints` array is initialized in the `initWithFrame` of SelectText. Also, I always check if the array is actually populated inside the view by putting a log in the function.

Now what I want to do is to access this array from another view. This is what I do:

**TextView.h**

```
#import "SelectText.h"

@interface TextView : UIView
{
   SelectText *txtSel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SelectText *txtSel;
```

**TextView.m**

```
@synthesize txtSel;

- (void)getDrawingPoints:(NSMutableArray *)pointArray
{
    self.pointArray = pointArray;
    NSLog(@"Array count: %d", [self.pointArray count]);
}
```

As you can see from the above code, I am trying to pass the data inside `txtSel.drawnPoints` to the `textView.pointArray` for later use. The problem is, the `txtSel.drawnPoints` always returns empty when I try to access it from another view. What am I doing wrong here?

**ADDITIONAL:**

This is how I instatiate `SelectText`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {
      self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
      if (self) {
         txtSel = [[SelectText alloc]init];
         [self addSubView:txtSel];

         //rest of code...
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that txtSel is being properly set, and is not simply nil? Objective-C will not complain at runtime if you try to get a property from nil.

Comment: To add to @ctrahey's point, try lazily instantiating txtSel.

Comment: You mentioned that you init the drawnPoints in viewDidLoad: of SelectText. However SelectText is a UIView which does not has a -viewDidLoad: to be overridden.

Comment: @xingzhi.sg Thanks for pointing it out! I got it mixed up. `TextView` is inside a ViewController. `TextView` is initialized in the `viewDidLoad:` of that ViewController. `SelectText` is initialized in the `initWithFrame:` of `TextView`

Comment: where did you call getDrawingPoints: ?

Comment: I called it inside another function in `TextView`. I created that function just to check if the array is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

change TextView class init method as below

```
- (id)initWithClassSelectText:(SelectText *)selectText {
     if ((self = [super init])) {
         txtSel =  selectText; 
     }
     return self;
}
```

And when you make an instance of TextView you use this:

```
TextView textView = [[TextView alloc] initWithClassSelectText:self];
```

now you can access all properties of SelectText class using `txtSel` object